# Spark: is DataFrame caching/persistence is transferred from one to another?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assume I have this code (Spark 1.6.2):

```
val finalDF: DataFrame = if (test) {
   val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(url).cache
   df.write.parquet(url2)
   df }
else
   sqlContext.read.parquet(other_url)
```

If I run `finalDF.unpersist`, will it indeed clean the data of `finalDF`/`df` from memory? If not, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (if test is true).

Basically when cache changes the dataframe (i.e. the dataframe is not immutable) which means that if finalDF is df then you will be unpersisting df. If test is false then df would not have been created to begin with and the result of sqlContext.read.parquet is not cached anyway but calling unpersist would not do any harm.

You can check it out yourself by looking at the UI (by default in port 4040) and checking out the storage tab. It would show the cached df before unpersist and after it would disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Spark drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) Algorithm. However, if you need to clean manually `dataFrame.unpersist()` works as you expected.
Refer to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence for detail